# Passing props through route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// App.js

import React from 'react'

function wate() {
let singleEpisode = {}
const [episodes, setEpisodes] = useState([])
const [singleEpi, setSingleEpic] = useState(singleEpisode)

const searchEpisode = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e)
    const { id, name, air_date, episode } = episodes[index]
    setSingleEpic({
      id: id,
      name: name,
      air_date: air_date,
      episode: episode
    })
return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <Router>
      <NavBar searchEpisode={searchEpisode} searchIt={searchIt} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/displayepisode' render={(props) => <DisplayEpisode {...props} epics={singleEpi} />} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.Fragment>
)
}
export default wate

// DisplayEpisode.js

import React from 'react'

function DisplayEpisode(props) {
const { id, name, air_date, episode } = props
console.log(props.epics)}

export default DisplayEpisode
```

Episodes has an array of objects more than 40 depending on the index value
I'm destructing id, name, air_date, episode. now I need to set those values to singleEpic as object and pass the singleEpic to child component and destructure them and use it.

Comment: Unrelated, but please consider using code blocks only for code, and indenting in a way that makes things as readable as possible.

Comment: in DisplayEpisode use the componentDidMount or an useEffect to show the props values

Comment: @Kiran Kumar V, This react code you provided will not build. There's too many errors and with what you've put I don't believe that you got it to compile. Please check it and and confirm? Because you child component is defined as `child` but you're passing `<DisplayEpisode  />` in render props?

Comment: Check your syntax...

Comment: @DaveNewton, Hi Sir, I'm new here I didn't know to format the code and also I'm a beginner in coding. I edited again hope it is little better now. could you please help me?

Comment: @MosiaThabo, Hi Sir, Thanks for checking it. I'm a beginner in coding. I read online we can pass props like that. I edited again I hope it is little better now.

Comment: @YoandryCollazo, Hi Sir, I need to display all the values in a card but when I log them in the console. it says undefined

Comment: Your code does not work and your question seems different from what you need, fix the open/close brackets, add the correct content for `DisplayEpisode` and improve your question.

Comment: @SheldonOliveira, I solved the problem I created an object with the same properties in singleEpisode and with empty values then updated it. It worked.

Comment: @KiranKumarV No worries—it’s just easier to help if it’s easy to read :) Glad you worked it out.

Comment: @DaveNewton. Thanks, I solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state wrong. You need to pass proper object into setSingleEpic method.

```
setSingleEpic({
      id: id,
      name: name,
      air_date: air_date,
      episode: episode
     }
    )
```

Comment: I solved the problem I created an object with the same properties in singleEpisode and with empty values then updated it. It worked. Thank You